# Differential Equations trouble

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I used wolfram alpha to solve the following differential equation: 
$$-G y'' + H y(x) x^2 = S y(x)$$
where $G,H$ and $S$ are positive constants.

and it gave the following result : 
[image]

My query is :

> What is the function "D" in the solution and what do the subscript and argument of the function represent ?

EDIT: If you are curious, the differential equation is Schrodinger equation for an electron in a quantum well with parabolic potential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are parabolic cylinder functions ([Wolfram's functions page](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/ParabolicCylinderD/), [DLMF section](http://dlmf.nist.gov/12)): it's another way of writing the Hermite functions when $n$ is not an integer. They solve the equation
$$ w'' + \left( \nu+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{z^2}{4} \right)w = 0.  $$

[Wolfram|Alpha does actually tell you what they are if you hover over the box with the solution in it.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-G%20y%27%27%28x%29%2BH%20x%5E2%20y%28x%29%20%3D%20S%20y%28x%29) Or at least, it tells me...

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to see the function when I hovered my cursor over the equation. Thanks again.